# Add new folder in Laravel 5 and set path

Tags: tinymce, filepath, laravel-5, subdirectory

I am new to `laravel 5`. I am creating a simple blog, in which i have to implement `tinymce` plugin for writing `Posts`, but i don't know how to do this, where i should place `tinymce` folder and how access in my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end of day javascript assets has to be in the public directory. 
I would recommend public/js.

The best way is using a package manager like bower to install tinymce.
Set up a .bowerrc file

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/bower_components"
}
```

Then configure gulp elixir properly that your tinymce components is copied and minified somewhere in public/js.

But to start with, just put it in public/js.